Maximal domain of Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{T}^n$ in $L^2$
I have read that the maximal domain
$$ \mathcal{D}(- \Delta) := \lbrace  f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)  :  - \Delta f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \rbrace $$
of the Laplacian $- \Delta: \mathcal{D}(- \Delta) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n),$ and the Laplacian is densely defined, closed and self-adjoint on it. This is also true on the flat torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ with $L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)$ resp. $H^2(\mathbb{T}^n).$ $\Delta f$ is defined in the sense of weak derivatives.
(But this is not true for bounded domains of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Dirichlet conditions e.g.)
Ist that correct? And could anyone recommend a reference where I could look up this result and the proof.
Thanks in advance!

Chapter 5 of "Partial Differential Equations I" by M. Taylor has everything. Particularly relevant for your question is section 5.1 and 5.A, which cover mapping properties of $\Delta$ associated with various boundary conditions, including Dirichlet and boundaryless. The $\mathbb{R}^n$ case (and the $\mathbb{T}^n$ case) should be straightforward from basic Fourier analysis, since $-\Delta$ acts as multiplication by $|\xi|^2$ on the Fourier side.
